# C++ I/O Rereading a file after EOF (was: Parsing a Comma Delimited Text File)

Tags: c++, io

Lets take a look at the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string usrFileStr,
    fileStr = "airNames.txt",  // declaring string literal
    sLine;                        // declaring a string obj

    fstream inFile;                  // declaring a fstream obj
    char ch;

    cout << "Enter a file: ";
    cin >> usrFileStr;


    inFile.open( usrFileStr.c_str(), ios::in ); 
    // at this point the file is open and we may parse the contents of it


    while ( !inFile.eof() )
    {
          getline ( inFile, sLine ); // store contents of txt file into str Obj
          for ( int x = 0; x < sLine.length(); x++ )
          {         
              if ( sLine[ x ] == ',' )break; // when we hit a comma stop reading 
              //cout << sLine[ x ];
          }
          cout << endl;
    }      



        while ( !inFile.eof() )  //read the file again until we reach end of file
        {
                // we will always want to start at this current postion;
              inFile.seekp( 6L, ios::cur );

              getline( inFile, sLine ); // overwrite the contents of sLine
              for ( int y = 0; y < sLine.length(); y++ )
              {
                  if ( sLine[ y ] == ',' )break; // hit a comma then goto seekp until eof
                  cout << sLine[ y ];
              }
              cout << endl;
        }

    inFile.clear();
    inFile.close();



    fgetc( stdin );
    return 0;
}
```

My text file format is similar to this:

```
string, string andthenspace, numbers, morenumbers
```

It doesn't look like I'm able to read the file twice. Checking for `EOF` each time..

The first while condition works, and it gives me what I need, the first field before the comma, and not including the comma.

So the second time I thought, ok just the `seekp(X, ios::cur)` function to start there on each iteration of the second while..

Unfortunately, it's not reading the file a second time..

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to clear the error bit on the stream after reading EOF the first time.
That is, as well as doing the seek operation.

Answer (score 3):

First, never test eof in your while loops, the flag will be true **after** you hit the end of the file, i.e. too late, the test must be done just after the read, and before using what you expect to have read. ->

```
while (std::getline(......))
```

Then, Jonathan Leffler gave you [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459744/c-i-o-rereading-a-file-after-eof-was-parsing-a-comma-delimited-text-file#459752), clear the state bits before the call to seekg. However, your approach seems somewhat complex as [Jamie pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459744/c-i-o-rereading-a-file-after-eof-was-parsing-a-comma-delimited-text-file#459761).

Comment: +1 but the situation is really a bit more complex than that, as EOF being set after a read doesn't mean that the read failed, either.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be going the wrong way about it:

```
FILE * file;
file = fopen ("file.txt","r");


if (file!=NULL){
        while (!feof(file)) {           
                fscanf(file,"%s ,%s ,%s ,%s",str1,str2,str3,str4);
        }
        fclose (file);
};
```

You can obviously expand the above example, I haven't had time to check it up it should work.

Comment: That's a rather C-like solution to a C++ problem, isn't it?  Why do you consider using the native C++ i/o operators incorrect?

Comment: This doesn't even say how to go back to the beginning of the file.

Comment: You didn't address his problem of rewinding the file at all.